# sscanf in c - get only specific digit/string

Tags: c, scanf

I have the following `sscanf`:

```
int four;
sscanf("1234&awe$asdf@3222*gr45", format, four);
```

I want this sscanf to put the value `3222` in the variable `four`.
What should be the `format` string?

`&` `$` `@` and `*` always stays the same. So other example of string inputs can be:

`"6345&346dfh$aweg@5463*nvm"` -> and `four` will be `5463`

`"0hjgf&456d$fhg@05645*pogyu"` -> and `four` will be `05645`

Im sorry if im not clear enough. Im trying to be as clearest as possible.

Edit:
I think that the way is this:

```
sscanf("1234&awe$asdf@3222*gr45", "@%d*", four);
```

Any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Nirock comment is on track.

```
int four;
// Anything not & (don't save it) followed by & then
// Anything not $ (don't save it) followed by $ then
// Anything not @ (don't save it) followed by @ then
// Anything not * (don't save it) followed by * then
// followed by an `int`
if (1 == sscanf(s, "%*[^&]&%*[^$]$%*[^@]@%*[^*]*%d", &four)) {
  ; // found it
}
```

Comment: If i want to do `Anything not & or @ (don't save it)` Is it simply `%*[^&@]`?

Comment: @Nirock Yes.  If you want "Anything not & or @ (don't save it) followed by one & or @ (don't save it)", use  `"%*[^&@]%*1[&@]"`.  BTW, be careful using the `%[]`, it can be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Your suggestion won't work, you need first to skip everything to the @, so `"%*[^@]@%d"`

Comment: Im sorry for beeing noob, But if i want to save the second one as well? What shall I do?

Comment: Is it something like `"%*[^&]&%s%*[^@]@%d"`

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    int four = 0;
    sscanf("1234&awe$asdf@3222*gr45", "%*[^@]@%d%*s", &four);
    printf("%d\n", four);
    return 0;
}
```

To get second number, you do:

```
sscanf("1234&awe$asdf@3222*gr45", "%*[^@]@%d%*[^0-9]%d", &four, &four1);
```